# Ava unbinds this for t.throws

Tags: ava

AVA seems to unbind the instance methods 'this'.

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayMyName() {
        const name = this.name;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            reject(new Error(name));
        });
    }
}

test('test', async (t) => {
    const person1 = new Person('Bob');
    const error = await t.throws(person1.sayMyName);
    t.is(error.message, 'Bob');
});
```

For the above code, I get this:

```
   85:     const error = await t.throws(person1.sayMyName);
   86:     t.is(error.message, 'Bob');
   87: });

  Difference:

  "CannBot read property \'name\' of undefinedb"
```

I've tried manually binding this promise like this:
person1.sayMyName.bind(person1), but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

`t.throws()` accepts a promise, so you just need to call your function:

```js
const error = await t.throws(person1.sayMyName());
```

---

#### Bonus tip:

If you only need to check the error message, your assertion could be simplified to the following:

```js
await t.throws(person1.sayMyName, 'Bob');
```

---

> AVA seems to unbind the instance methods 'this'.

No, that's how `this` works in JavaScript. If you pass a class method, you need to bind it to its instance to preserve `this`. You might find my [`auto-bind`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind) module handy for this.